# The madness of a master

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, situation

> It was midnight. Mr. Holmes was suffering from abdominal pain, shortness of breath, pain in the bones, skin lesions and whatnot? So in this condition, why would Mr. Holmes drive to Brazilian Churches, polishing and ruining everything on his way, and why would he go to Lehe in a Lehe in Lower Saxony, Germany while listening to IIIEEI? Clearly, there is something wrong. Can you see the reason Lestrade? I don’t know why he is harming himself. After losing his ‘eights’ and getting hit by a wedge-shaped wood, he has gone viler. What has gotten into him? Why is he behaving so odd, Lestrade? It doesn't suit him at all does it?

What is the hidden message here? How is all related to Holmes?

Hint 1:

> New tag added (recently)